# SQLite dictionary database optimization

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary

I am writing a dictionary application. I have a large static SQLite database with one table (100k+ rows) and an »_id«, »word« and »description« columns. Entries are lexicographically ordered by »word«. I use the code below and afterTextChanged(Editable searchText) to make instant searches in the database, loading a selection of rows into an ArrayList, and from there to a list adapter.
The code works, however, it is not very efficient, i.e.:

- Searches for words beginning with »z« are much slower than those starting with an »a«.
- After inputing »abc«, when user inputs »d«, search for »abcd« starts from the begining instead from the first occurence of »abc«.
- Queries for nonexisting strings last very long, but we know that say, »abcdx« can only appear between »abcd« and »abce«.

Is there a way how I can optimize for those properties? Are there any ready-made solutions for dictionaries? Sorry, I am new to this.

I canot replace »LIKE« with »>=« for example, since words also consists of some non-ASCII characters and »>=« query doesn't work with them.

```
//---retrieves a database subset in the range (MATCH-RowsBefore, MATCH+RowsAfter)---
public Cursor getSearch(Editable typedKeys) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor sCursor =
            db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, word FROM dict WHERE word LIKE ? LIMIT 1", 
            new String[]{typedKeys + "%"});
    if (sCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        SearchedRow = Integer.parseInt(sCursor.getString(0));
        int newstart = SearchedRow - RowsBefore;
        String curlen = Integer.toString(RowsBefore + RowsAfter + 1);
        sCursor = db.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] {_id,
                word}, _id + ">=" + newstart, null, null, null, null, curlen);
    }
    return sCursor;
}
```

Comment: If your _ID is truly defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, starting your where with "WHERE _ID > " + Integer.toString(lastID)  + " AND ( ... LIKES GO HERE ...)"  No math required. Also, the B-TREE is used to position the start of the search. No sequential scan up to the starting point. It's sequential after that. I'm hitting a 7,000 row table using the last id and up to 4 anded likes with a limit of 12.  Instant retreival.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the point two. It works as long as I manage lastID properly. For the difference in search time between "a" and "z" I will still have to find a different solution. Any ideas about the third point - limiting the scope of search?

Comment: I'm not sure of your structure, by I speeded things up by indexing one of my 'pointer' fields that was normally searched sequentially. THe query consisted of the primary key and the indexed field.